# Why does my applet flash for every repaint?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I found some Java game code online and I am trying to modify it.  I converted it from JFrame to Applet, but then my game started to blink every time I repaint screen.  I tried double buffering but no difference.

Source:

```
    private void paintDisks(Graphics g) {
        try {
            for (Disk d : disk)
                paintDisk(g, d);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            paintDisks(g); // retry so the disks never not get painted
        }
    }
    private void paintDisk(Graphics g, Disk d) {
        if (d == null)
            return;
        if (diskimg[d.player] == null) {
            g.setColor(colour[d.player]);
            g.fillOval((int)d.x - 1, (int)d.y - 1, 32, 32);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(diskimg[d.player],
                       (int)d.x - 1, (int)d.y - 1,
                        32, 32, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // paint real panel stuff
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics gr; 
        if (offScreenBuffer==null ||
              (! (offScreenBuffer.getWidth(this) == this.size().width
              && offScreenBuffer.getHeight(this) == this.size().height)))
        {
            offScreenBuffer = this.createImage(size().width, size().height);
        }

        gr = offScreenBuffer.getGraphics();

        gr.clearRect(0,0,offScreenBuffer.getWidth(this),offScreenBuffer.getHeight(this));

        // paint the disks
        paintDisks(gr);

        // paint the curser ontop of the disks
        paintCurser(gr);

        g.drawImage(offScreenBuffer, 0, 0, this);   
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(9, 1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be easier to debug, for you and us, if you first strip this down to a simpler self-contained example that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** do not call `super.paint()` in your `Board.paint()` method.

**Long answer:** Applet is also a container with its own display properties including a background color which you set via `setBackground(Color.WHITE);` as part of your constructor.  By invoking `super.paint(g)` you are causing the applet to paint its white background to the display graphics, as well as invoke any contained component painting.  This is the cause of the flicker - each paint cycle, it is painting the on-screen display white then copying your `offscreenBuffer` image to the on-screen display.

Probably it is best to be explicit, forget about the Applet background, remove `super.paint(g)`, and just do all the paint steps yourself.  You'll need to replace `clearRect()` with `setColor()` and `fillRect()`.

Also you should implement `update()` as well.

```
@Override
public void update(Graphics g) { paint(g); }

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // no super.paint(g)

    if (offScreenBuffer==null ||
          (! (offScreenBuffer.getWidth(this) == this.size().width
          && offScreenBuffer.getHeight(this) == this.size().height)))
    {
        offScreenBuffer = this.createImage(size().width, size().height);
    }

    Graphics gr = offScreenBuffer.getGraphics();

    // blank the canvas
    gr.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    gr.fillRect(0,0,offScreenBuffer.getWidth(this),offScreenBuffer.getHeight(this));

    // paint the disks
    paintDisks(gr);

    // paint the curser ontop of the disks
    paintCurser(gr);

    g.drawImage(offScreenBuffer, 0, 0, this);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the game engine [Bonsai](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/Bonsai-Game-Library) from [Ivo Wetzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170224/ivo-wetzel). I like it a lot.

It uses `BufferStrategy`, which is, I think the best way to double buffer.